# Erro ao Preencher uma DropDownListFor There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou com um erro ao passar o conteúdo do controller para a view, estou fazendo desta forma, a ViewBag esta sendo preenchida com os dados.

Na minha aplicação eu seleciono os itens:

```html
        public List<TB_EMPRESA> ListarTodos()
        {
            var strQuery = "select * from tb_empresa";

            using (contexto = new Contexto())
            {
                var retornoDataReader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                return TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(retornoDataReader);
            }

        }
```

no controller:

```html
        // GET: CadastroUsuario
        public ActionResult Index()
        {


            //lista empresa
            var tbuscarEmpresa = new EmpresaAplicacao();
            var listarEmpresa = tbuscarEmpresa.ListarTodos();
            ViewBag.Empresa = listarEmpresa;


            return View();
        }
```

na View

```html
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.tbidempresa)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.tbidempresa.IDEMPRESA, ViewBag.Empresa as SelectList, "Selecione um item..", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.tbidempresa)
            </div>
```

Imagem do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No controller é necessário o seguinte ajuste:

```html
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            //lista empresa
            var tbuscarEmpresa = new EmpresaAplicacao();
            var listarEmpresa =  tbuscarEmpresa.ListarTodos();
            ViewBag.Empresa = new SelectList( listarEmpresa,"IDEMPRESA", "RAZAO_SOCIAL"); //esta informação com o nome dos campos

            return View();
        }
```